# How to show an affine variety in $\mathbb{A}^{n}$ either has finite cardinality or equal to that of $k$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How to show an affine variety in $\mathbb{A}^{n}$ either has finite cardinality or equal to that of $k$? I do not know how to solve this via elementary methods.

Comment: are you allowed to use Noether normalization?

Comment: I am not working on homework, but Noether normalization only applies to projective varieties right?

Comment: I take a look by googling, and found the popular version is different from what I know. Still, I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: I'm guessing $k$ is a field, but when you write $\mathbb{A}^k$, it looks like it could also be an integer. Is this notation supposed to mean the affine line over $k$? I think it might be a bit more clear if you used the notation $\mathbb{A}_k^1$ (if this is what you mean).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, clarified; also by Noether normalization lemma this is immediate.